# Insertion Sort - troubles reading MIT Intro to Algos

Tags: algorithm, insertion-sort, array-algorithms

The MIT Intro to Algorithms describes insertion sort as:

[image: MIT Algo image]

I wrote this in Python as:

```
def sort(A):
    for j in range(1, len(A)):
        key = A[j];
        i = j - 1;

        # i > 0 should be i >= 0
        while i > 0 and A[i] > key:
            A[i + 1] = A[i]
            i = i - 1;
        A[i + 1] = key

    return A
```

However the line `while i > 0` introduces a bug - the first two keys are in the wrong positions. Changing this to `while i >= 0` fixes this problem.

Why is this not included in the MIT Intro book? Am I reading it wrong?

Answer (score 2):

The algorithm in the book is assuming indexing from 1 to `A.length`, inclusive, which is why it starts at an index of 2.  Python has array indexing from 0 to `len(A) - 1`.  You corrected for that in your `range`, but you neglected to correct for it in the loop test.  Doing so fixes the problem.

Comment: Ah okay - makes sense. Interesting that they don't zero index the pseudocode, although I guess that it might be better from a learning perspective.

Comment: Mathematicians like 1-based indexing, most (but not all) languages have adopted 0-based since the days of C.  The result has been decades of off-by-one errors...

Answer (score 0):

@pjs is exactly right. I'll add that a methodical way to convert an algorithm written for 1-based arrays to 0-based with no off-by-1 errors is to use the algorithm as-is except subtract 1 at each array reference and then use algebra to simplify.  Here you'd end up with:

```
def sort(A):
  for j in range(2, len(A) + 1): # +1 is because Python ranges exclude high limit
    key = A[j - 1]
    i = j - 1
    while i > 0 and A[i - 1] > key:
      A[i + 1 - 1] = A[i - 1]
      i = i - 1
    A[i + 1 - 1] = key
  return A
```

Of course it's easy to simplify by removing `+ 1 - 1`, since that's adding zero! The result works fine.

If you want to make the code prettier with the outer range starting at 1 rather than 2, make the substitution `jj = j - 1`, which (adding 1 to both sides) means `j = jj + 1`:

```
def sort(A):
  for jj in range(1, len(A)):
    key = A[jj + 1 - 1]
    i = jj + 1 - 1
    while i > 0 and A[i - 1] > key:
      A[i] = A[i - 1]
      i = i - 1
    A[i] = key
  return A
```

Again removing `+ 1 - 1`s, we have

```
def sort(A):
  for jj in range(1, len(A)):
    key = A[jj]
    i = jj 
    while i > 0 and A[i - 1] > key:
      A[i] = A[i - 1]
      i = i - 1
    A[i] = key
  return A
```

This looks great, and I'd stop here. But yet another variation is possible with the substitution `ii = i - 1` or `i = ii + 1`.

```
def sort(A):
  for jj in range(1, len(A)):
    key = A[jj]
    ii + 1 = jj 
    while ii + 1 > 0 and A[ii + 1 - 1] > key:
      A[ii + 1] = A[ii + 1 - 1]
      ii + 1 = ii + 1 - 1
    A[ii + 1] = key
  return A
```

Hmmm... Those assignments to `ii` look weird. But we can straighten everything out with algebra yet again.

```
def sort(A):
  for jj in range(1, len(A)):
    key = A[jj]
    ii = jj - 1  # Subtracted 1 from both sides
    while ii >= 0 and A[ii] > key: # x + 1 > 0 iff x >= 0
      A[ii + 1] = A[ii]
      ii = ii - 1 # Subtracted 1 from both sides and simplified
    A[ii + 1] = key
  return A
```

Lo and behold, we have the code you proposed. Works every time.